"AllChem" is not defined in using rdkit
I am trying to use rdkit by following the RDKit 2024.03.4 documentation.
I tried the following code, but all I got it an error code showing "AllChem" is not defined. Anything I can do to resolve this? RD kit was installed by pip install. Thank you.
I tried the following code, but all I got it an error code showing "AllChem" is not defined.
`template = Chem.MolFromSmiles('c1nccc2n1ccc2')
AllChem.Compute2DCoords(template)`


Please show your import statements.

I tested the code you mentioned on Getting Started with the RDKit in Python. I believe you might forget to import AllChem module per the webpage. The code below works for me:
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
template = Chem.MolFromSmiles('c1nccc2n1ccc2')
AllChem.Compute2DCoords(template)

Please let me know and good luck!

That works great! Thank you. Noe I can follow the instruction to go further

Glad it helped! You can hit the checkmark to mark this question as solved. Cheers!
